# Create Live DVD/USB from already installed Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, live-usb

I am trying to create a LIVE ISO of already installed and configured Ubuntu OS which has different tools installed and a running web server.

I want to make a **BOOTABLE LIVE ISO** with all software installed and configurations so I can give demo to other people which most people do sometimes. I have used *Respin and Remastersys* couple of years ago but now both are obsolete for Ubuntu version 18.04.

Comment: I think you can only clone it. your question is very clear but for live iso you need to customize the downloaded iso only.

Comment: See [Debian Live](http://live.debian.org) for the appropriate tools to create a real bootable Live image. Those are the tools that the Ubuntu Desktop Team uses.

Comment: You can create an .img file using Disks and extract that using mkusb in Linux or Win32DiskImager in Windows. I have heard that Systemback is working for under 4GB systems.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just install Ubuntu 18.04 on, for example, a USB drive and then you can use something like Clonezilla to create an image with only the used blocks. It will come out quite large but there are few other options left.

Comment: Disks also works good for creating and restoring a USB disk images. The images can also be extracted using mkusb or Win32DiskImager. They can also be compressed to a more convenient size. One drawback is that if you want to extract to a separate partition, grub needs to be installed in an extra step.